# Removing red eye in PHP using Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I'm trying to adapt the script available here [http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/redeye/index.php][1] in PHP using the API version of Imagick.

Actually, the selection is done in jQuery then passed to the following script to draw the selection.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
    extract($_POST);

    // Load the original image
    $image = new Imagick($path);

    // Duplicate and desaturate the original image
    $image2 = clone $image;
    $image2->modulateImage(15, 0, 100);

    // Create the mask on which the selection will be drawn
    $image3 = clone $image;
    $image3->colorfloodfillimage(new ImagickPixel('white'), 18, new ImagickPixel('white'), 0, 1);

    foreach ($redeye as $selection){
        try{
            $draw = new ImagickDraw();
            $draw->setstrokewidth(0);
            $draw->setstrokecolor(new ImagickPixel('black'));
            $draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel( 'black' ));
            $draw->setfillalpha(1);
            $draw->ellipse( $selection['ox'], $selection['oy'], $selection['rx'], $selection['ry'], 0, 360 );
            $image3->drawImage($draw);
        } catch (ImagickException $ie){
            echo $ie->getMessage();
        }
    }  
?>
```

I know very little about image processing and don't know how to merge the 3 layers.
I don't really understand the code of the convert function when merging the layer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

```
convert $tmpA1 $tmpA2 $tmpA3 -compose over -composite $tmpA2
```

As I understand this should be written like the following using the API:

```
$image2->compositeImage($image3,Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$image2->compositeImage($image2,Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$image2->compositeImage($image,Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
```

Then

```
convert $tmpA2 \( $tmpA1 -modulate 100,0,100 \) $tmpA4 -compose over -composite $outfile
```

Should be written like that:

```
$image->modulateImage(100, 0, 100);
$image->compositeImage($image,Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,0, 0);
$image->compositeImage($image2,Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER,0, 0);
```

But I don't understand this part:

```
convert $tmpA3 ( +clone -morphology close disk:$rad $dilation ) -compose difference -composite -auto-level -negate -threshold 0 -negate $tmpA4
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors specifically, or if not that, what is happening that you aren't expecting?

Comment: No errors at all, I just don't know how to merge the layers. I've tried different things but all I manage to achieve is to show the original image with the black selected areas on it ...